# Multiselector doesn't execute animations simultaneously in jQuery

Tags: jquery, delay, simultaneous

When i run

```
$("[id^=menuItem]").fadeOut(1000);
```

the fading out is done simultaneously to all the components. However, bore that i execut a for loop doing something else to the elements, upon the completion of which i wish to fade out all of them at the same time by

```
var i;
for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    $("div#item" + i).delay(i * 1000).fadeIn(1500);
$("[id^=item]").fadeOut(400);
```

For some reason, the fading out starts on the first element before the second, which is started before the third etc. It creates a very cool effect, indeed, but it's not what i need to achieve in my project.

Why does it happen??

I suspect that the answer will be that the final fading out starts as soon as each component is done with the initial fading in. In that case, my question will be reformulated to how one can delay the execution of the multiselected fadeout until a certain something has been finished (i.e. the last item has done fading in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has probably to do with the fact that the different components get ready for the next step at different times. Maybe i should use callback function after the fade in. Of course, that would execute a whole bunch callbacks so one will need to use $.when/.then syntax.